# Force acting on an object in Y-Z plane

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

An object is placed in the Y-Z plane , a force $\textbf{F} = f_x \textbf{e}_x+ f_y \textbf{e}_y+ f_z \textbf{e}_z$  acts on it.

What components of force will be acting on it?
By that I mean which component is non-zero, $f_x$, $f_y$, or $f_z$?

Comment: Since the force has contributions from all three components, all three components will act on the object.  The components do not act independently; the components combine into one single force.

Comment: Your question is confusing. I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: What has the location of an object got to do with the components of a force acting on it?

Comment: Since it's in Y-Z plane ..... only Y and Z components will act on the object.... am I right?

Comment: Does the same applies if there is an electric field with the same magnitude acting on the object instead of a force?